# Slonik: How to safely query a JSONB object using `JSONB_PATH_MATCH()`?

Tags: postgresql, slonik

I have aggregated JSONB objects in a column of a PostgreSQL table that looks similar to this:

```
  id  | agg_jsonb_objects
------+---------------------------------------------------------
   1  | {"recordA": {"fieldA": "A"}, "recordB": {"fieldA": "B"}}
```

Next, I'd like to find all rows where any "fieldA" has value "B", which I could do as follows:

```
SELECT id
FROM ...
WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(agg_jsonb_objects, 'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == "B"))')
```

This works well in the terminal, but I'm struggling to put together safe query in the server, which uses Slonik to build queries.

I get it to work using `raw()` but that's not acceptable as it's unsafe.

```js
const filterValue = 'B';
sql`
    SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(${sql.identifier(['agg_jsonb_objects'])}, 'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == ${raw(filterValue)}))')
`;
// Works.
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this but I'm get the following error:

```js
const filterValue = 'B';
sql`
    SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(${sql.identifier(['agg_jsonb_objects'])}, 'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == ${filterValue}))')
`;
// could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Am I just doing something wrong with the syntax or is there a fundamentally different (and better) way to do this with Slonik?

**EDIT1**: Following @Bergi's advice, I changed it to the following, which does appear to work:

```js
const filterValue = 'B';
const valueForJsonbPathMatchExpression = `exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == "${filterValue}"))`;
sql`
    SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(${sql.identifier(['agg_jsonb_objects'])}, ${valueForJsonbPathMatchExpression})
`;
// Works.
```

Clear step forward, thanks a bunch! Still requires some manual preparation, e.g. adding quotes for strings but not numeric values and adjusting comparator for greater/lesser than queries. I wonder if that can be simplified?

Comment: Try using variables in the json path expression

Comment: You first need to escape the value as a JSON (path) string literal, then the whole json path expression as a SQL literal.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi! That's a lot better already (see my edit in the original post). Is that how you intended me to do it? Now I'm just wondering whether there is a different/better way to do this so I don't need to handle quotes (strings/numeric values).

Comment: Better use `…${JSON.stringify(filterValue)}…` instead of `…"${filterValue}"…`, to avoid "json path expression injections" like `B = '" or "" = "'`. Though tbh I'm not 100% sure that json path literals use json syntax, I haven't seen this stated anywhere explicitly

Comment: Good point. I _think_ Slonik would escape that. But won't `…${JSON.stringify(filterValue)}…` add quotes to numeric values? I also need to be able to do `JSONB_PATH_MATCH('agg_jsonb_objects', 'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA > ${someValue}))')`.

Comment: No, Slonik cannot do anything about it. Slonik only escapes the SQL-level (jsonpath) value literal. But it doesn't prevent jsonpath syntax errors in that literal (not even knowing the type of the SQL literal), and it cannot know what your expression is meant to do. `exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == "" or "" = ""))` is a perfectly fine predicate - it just doesn't do what you want. It's more limited than an SQLI, but still a risk.

Comment: And no, `JSON.stringify` does not add quotes if `filterValue` is a number.

Comment: Yeah, you're right of course, Slonik cannot protect me from that kind of injection. I'll need to have a think whether that's acceptable, need to take additional measure or use an entirely different approach. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two levels of escaping that you need to consider when building this query. First, there's the JSON string literal within the JSON path expression. Second, there's the SQL jsonpath value that needs to be formatted as a literal or be passed via parameter.

You'd use `JSON.stringify` for the former, and Slonik interpolation to generate a parameterised query for the latter, and write

```
sql`
    SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(
        ${ sql.identifier(['agg_jsonb_objects']) },
        ${ 'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == ' + JSON.stringify(filterValue) + '))' }
    )
`;
```

Alternatively, you can pass the `filterValue` as part of a `vars` object to `jsonb_path_match`, and reference it from a static JSON path expression:

```
sql`
    SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE JSONB_PATH_MATCH(
        ${ sql.identifier(['agg_jsonb_objects']) },
        'exists($ ?(@.**.fieldA == $filterValue))',
        ${ sql.jsonb({ filterValue }) }
    )
`;
```

Btw, I recommend to use a [strict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#STRICT-AND-LAX-MODES) JSON path expression when working with `**`, and you can simplify the whole expression to just `$.**.fieldA == $filterValue`.